# Change folder name in TFS project without mapping

Tags: c#, api, tfs, tfs-sdk

It is possible to change folder name in TFS project on the server without getting the file locally?

I am trying to do that with the API without results, all the ways that i found over the internet include get workspace and checkout of the file but its not good for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You need a workspace and to get at least the folder itself. It probably suffices to create a workspace that only contains the folder as a single mapped item, perform a non-recursive get operation, pend the rename and check it in.